# What is the default location for saved cplex solutions

Tags: python, cplex, pyomo

Running cplex/pyomo the solver found a solution and it reported saved somewhere though I closed before taking note, can't find over the web where is it stored.

running windows, anyone?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how exactly pyomo invokes CPLEX to store solutions on disk. The default behavior of CPLEX is to store solutions in the current working directory. The solution file will have a suffix of either `.sol` or `.mst`.

Answer (score 0):

by default pyomo generates a json file results.json in the directory where you call pyomo.

Let me take the [bus example](https://medium.com/@alexfleischer_84755/optimization-simply-do-more-with-less-zoo-buses-and-kids-66940178db6) in pyomo:

In the file pyomobus.py

```
from pyomo.environ import *

model = ConcreteModel()

model.nbBus = Var([40,30], domain=PositiveIntegers)

model.OBJ = Objective(expr = 600*model.nbBus[40] + 480*model.nbBus[30])

model.nbKids = Constraint(expr = 40*model.nbBus[40] + 30*model.nbBus[30] >= 300)
```

then in that directory if you type

```
pyomo solve pyomobus.py  --solver=cplex
```

you will get a file results.json in that directory where you will read

```
"Problem": {},
            "Status": "optimal",
            "Variable": {
                "nbBus[30]": {
                    "Value": 2.0
                },
                "nbBus[40]": {
                    "Value": 6.0
                }
```